# Create stretch header using autolayout via storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, uistoryboard

### Problem

Hi, I've faced with the following problem. I am creating header consists from three block via storyboard. I am trying to make it stretch to fit all devices using autolayout.
I have three images:

- Left corner image (has round left border)
- Centre image (is just a line)
- Right corner image (has round right border)

Example of right image corner:
[image: right corner image]

I want these three images to be one line in a centre.
The result should looks like this:
[image: full header]

### First solution

I've created following constraints:
for the left block:

- Width = 152
- Height = 50
- Leading to superview
- Top to superview

**Left image constraints:**
[image: Left Image]

for the middle block:

- Height = 50
- Trailing to left image = 0
- Leading to right image = 0
- Top to superview

Middle image constraints:
[image: Middle image]

for the right image:

- Width = 152
- Height = 50
- Trailing to superview
- Top to superview

**Right image constraints:**
[image]

When I run my app on a simulator everything works properly and I see good result on all devices but I if I use this constraints I got a lot of warnings in the storyboard and also in console: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`

Actually warning in console appears because of this

> - Trailing to left image equal to 0
> - Leading to right image equal to 0

### Second solution

I've also tried to make following constraints for the middle image:

- delete trailing constraint to left image
- add leading constraint to the superview equal to width of right image

But this solution creates even more warnings

### Question

Is there a solution how to create such header through the storyboard and not to make width as a constant and update it for every screen width?

Comment: Did you mix up the trailing and leading constraints for the middle image?

Comment: @Code What do you mean by mix up constraints?

Comment: I think it should be leading to left and trailing to right.

Comment: @Code no, if leading will be to the left then the middle image will start from the same place as left and the end of the middle image will be at the same place with the right image

Comment: I mean leading of middle = trailing of left, etc. Can you post an image of your constraints?

Comment: @Code you can check images that I've added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need all constraints that you wrote, but as well you need to add constraints that says that all this three images has the same width. 
For example tell that first has same as second and second has same as third. And as well you need to remove width constraints.

Reason of such errors is that you setting two items width = 152*2 = 304. If this value is grater than screen width than you will have warnings.

Comment: But all three images should not have same width. Middle image will always had separate width. The main problem that I have is exactly that fact that middle image should have an ability to be stretch and to change it width. I have warnings because `Trailing to left image equal to 0` and `Leading to right image equal to 0`. If I remove one of them warnings disappear.

Comment: simulator iphone 5 and iphone 6

Comment: Than I can suppose only one thing how to solve it. 

1) left image - width, height, leading to superview, top to superview

2) right image - width, height, traling to superview, top to superview

3)midle image - center horisontaly, top, height, proportional width to superview.


than all three views won't be connected. Still that's not good solution. Why do you need to have width equal 152?

Comment: what do you mean by proportional width? How to make it? Do you mean to change trough the code? About 152. I thought firstly that if I make left and right images stretch than the rounded corners will be pixeled and borders radius will not be smooth. Secondly don't use think that there is a possible situation when 3*width != width of screen (there might be 1pt difference, but it could be noticeably)

Comment: To make proportional width you need to change constraints multiplier. It can be done in builder. And to left the same rounded corners you can use other image render mode(what I mean that your image view can have size not as image resolution, but other render mode just will cut image on needed side). That will give us, that corners will have the same corner radius, just end of image(which is just a line) will be cut.

Comment: As well, this border is so simple, that you do not need to use images, you can easily draw it on your own. It will be much more flexible for changes and will give you much more possibilities. I think it would be the best solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115444/discussion-between-danny-and-volodymyr).

Answer (score 0):

The middle constraints are wrong. They should be:

- middle.leading = left.trailing
- middle.trailing = right.leading

Comment: It is how it is done now, and this perfectly works except it produce a lot of warnings.

Comment: @Danny It's how it's done now? But your image says otherwise.